# Invalid datetime format in laravel while sending data from angular

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, associative-array

Can anyone help me how to solve this issue? I have a request data from angular that I had passed to the laravel backend for inserting multiple rows at a time. But I got below error. I tried running the below query in Mysql, it is working fine there but not from laravel.

How can I fix this??

Request data from Angular (API):

```
[
  {
    "customer_id": 3,
    "check_in_date": "2020-07-30T00:00:00.000Z",
    "check_out_date": "2020-07-31T00:00:00.000Z",
    "room_id": 2
  },
  {
    "customer_id": 3,
    "check_in_date": "2020-07-29T00:00:00.000Z",
    "check_out_date": "2020-07-31T00:00:00.000Z",
    "room_id": 3
  }
]
```

Migration Table

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('reservations', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->bigIncrements('id');
        $table->unsignedBigInteger('room_id');
        $table->foreign('room_id')->references('id')->on('rooms');
        $table->unsignedBigInteger('customer_id');
        $table->foreign('customer_id')->references('id')->on('customers');
        $table->unsignedBigInteger('booking_id')->nullable();
        $table->foreign('booking_id')->references('id')->on('bookings');
        $table->dateTime('check_in_date');
        $table->dateTime('check_out_date');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

Controller of reservation:

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $reservation = Reservation::insert($request->all());
    
    return $this->jsonResponse(true, 'Reservation has been created successfully.', $reservation);
}


private function jsonResponse($success = false, $message = '', $data = null)
{
    return response()->json([
        'success' => $success,
        'message' => $message,
        'data' => $data
    ]);
}
```

Error:

```
 "message": "SQLSTATE[22007]: Invalid datetime format: 1292 Incorrect datetime value: '2020-07- 
 29T00:00:00.000Z' for column 'check_in_date' at row 1 

 (SQL: insert into `reservations` (`check_in_date`, `check_out_date`, `customer_id`, `room_id`)

 values (2020-07-30T00:00:00.000Z, 2020-07-31T00:00:00.000Z, 3, 2),
        (2020-07-29T00:00:00.000Z, 2020- 07-31T00:00:00.000Z, 3, 3))",
 "exception": "Illuminate\\Database\\QueryException",
```

Comment: are those atom date?

Comment: _I tried running the below query in Mysql, it is working fine_ Then you didn't run that exact query.

Comment: It also helps if you show us the input data that matches the Error query. 2 inputs does not generate 3 outputs and the dates are different. It all matters

Comment: MySQL expects a date in the format `2020-07-29 00:00:00.000` so run your dates through a `DateTime` or `Carbon` call to reformat it correctly

Comment: Yes the query works fine in Mysql but in through laravel application I got above error.

Comment: Ok i will try that @RiggsFolly

Comment: Did you see @Berto99 answer, because that is basically what he has done

Comment: Yes I tried his answer. But I got this error saying "  "message": "Trying to get property 'check_in_date' of non-object",
    "exception": "ErrorException"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the dates have the wrong format, try casting them using `Carbon`, it should serialize automatically to the correct form that your DBMS wants:

```
use Carbon\Carbon;
...
function store(Request $request)
{
    $all = array_map(function($el){
        $el->check_in_date = Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d\TH:i:s+', $el->check_in_date);
        $el->check_out_date = Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d\TH:i:s+', $el->check_out_date);
        return $el;
    }, $request->all());
    $reservation = Reservation::insert($all);
    
    return $this->jsonResponse(true, 'Reservation has been created successfully.', $reservation);
}
```

Edit: seems like there was some issue about accessing the object fields, solved using `$el['check_in_date']` instead of `$el->check_in_date`

Comment: "message": "Trying to get property 'check_in_date' of non-object",
    "exception": "ErrorException"

Comment: I checked the type of request gettype($request)... It returns me object

Comment: I changed $el->check_in_date to $el['check_in_date'].... Same goes for check_out_date.   Thank You @Berto99 ... It works for me now..

Comment: @susmitarai sorry, i was away... it's strange since by what you are showing on the question, `el` should contains objects